# How can I return a list of substrings contained within a string that match an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to rewrite a Python discord bot in Javascript for obvious reasons. I'm trying to set up a 'banned word' list, so if someone says a word in that list, the message will be deleted and they'll get a warning. Easy enough. My code for that is:

```
bot.on('messageCreate', message => {
    const bannedwords = ['word1', 'word2'];
    if (bannedwords.some(term => message.content.includes(term))) {
        message.delete();
        message.author.send(`Woah there buddy! You can't say that.`)
    }
});
```

My question is: How can I return a list of the matching substrings?

So: if a person sends "My name is person1 and I think person3 is bad" when the bannedwords list says `['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4']` I want the function to return `['person1', 'person3']`. How can I do this?

In python, I used `[word for word in bannedwords if word in message.content]` if that helps any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter()` to return what `bannedwords` were found in `message.content`. This will return an array of matches.

```js
bot.on('messageCreate', message => {
    const bannedwords = ['word1', 'word2'];
    const matches = bannedwords.filter(term => message.content.includes(term));
    if (matches.length) {
        message.delete();
        message.author.send(`Woah there buddy! You can't say that.`)
 
        console.log(`The banned words used were ${matches.join(', ')}`);
    }
});
```

Documentation on [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)